# How can i transfer an image through facebook chat application in android?

Tags: android, facebook, asmack

I am new to android. I am developing facebook chat application which has the feature of sending images to friend who is in chat list.
I tried to do by using asmack api FileTranfer classes to send image. But, there was a problem in sending.
Here is the code to transfer a file using asmack api.

```
// Create the file transfer manager
        ConnectionConfiguration config =    new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222, "chat.facebook.com");
           config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
          config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);

      FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(new XMPPConnection(config));

      // Create the outgoing file transfer
      OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(friend_id);

      // Send the file
      transfer.sendFile(new File("path of image from sd card"), "You won't believe this!");

Here, throwing a NullPointerException at the FileTransferManager statement
```

Is there any method to send image,audio,video in facebook official api for android.
Please advice me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the documentation for the [Facebook Chat API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/)?
It clearly states in the *Features and Limitations* that:

> Sending and receiving plain-text messages (not HTML messages)

It says nothing about images.
Also:

> Facebook Chat should be compatible with every XMPP client, but is not
>   a full XMPP server. It should be thought of as a proxy into the world
>   of Facebook Chat on www.facebook.com. As a result, it has several
>   behaviors that differ slightly from what you would expect from a
>   traditional XMPP service

As far as I'm aware, you can not send images using the chat API, and the docs pretty much back this up.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Nitzan Tomer. So there's no way? But how come i'm getting the url message to my chat message box when some other user sending an image from other facebook chat apps?

Comment: I did not say that there's no way, just that I'm not aware of one, and that the documentation hints that you can't. I've never used any facebook chat apps and don't know of any examples that does that. Here's a link that confirms it though: http://www.wikiopens.com/can-you-insert-a-picture-into-a-facebook-chat.html